# MS SQL - CASE vs IF performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function in SQL that performs a check against one of a number of tables based on an input parameter. E.G.

```
CREATE FUNCTION demo
(
    @Classification INT,
    @ClassificationValue INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Classification = 1
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT CountryRegionId FROM table_1 WHERE id = @ClassificationValue)
        BEGIN
            RETURN 1;
        END
    END 
    IF @Classification = 2
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT CountryRegionId FROM table_2 WHERE id = @ClassificationValue)
        BEGIN
            RETURN 1;
        END
    END 
    RETURN 0;
END
```

This is a simplified situation, and in reality there are more target tables to choose from.

### MY Question

In C# or most other languages it would be better to use a switch statement rather than successive if statements, as a hash would be used. Is this the same in SQL (given that case statements can contain logical expressions - e.g. Case When a <5 - obviously can't be hashed.

Comment: You can't parameterize table names in SQL, and `CASE` *expressions* and `IF` *statements* occupy different parts of the language and aren't interchangeable.

Comment: I'd also query your table design, if it's anything like what you've shown (and likely similarly, since you seem to think it makes sense to have this single function that queries all of these different tables) - you appear to have attribute splitting going on - that is, where what you should probably have is a *single* table containing the `Classification` as a separate column, you instead have multiple tables where the classification has been embedded in the *name* of the table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you about the classification column - that is the way I would have done it, but I am working on a system where the table structure is already fixed. There are also business reasons for that table structure (not sure how justifiable they are).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of the comparison in the `if` is, essentially, *nothing* compared to the cost of the `exists` statement -- even with an index on the appropriate keys.

Don't worry about such micro-optimizations unless you literally have thousands and thousands of comparisons.

In that case, I would first recommend ordering the comparisons by the most likely-to-match first.  Then, I would suggest looking into an alternative data structure where you can compare the id in a single table.  Having tables that are so similar is often a sign that you can improve the data structure with fewer bigger tables.

And, finally, if you are really concerned about the number of comparisons, use nested `if`s to get `O(log n)` comparisons.  As an example, "8" comparisons would have the structure:

```
if @Classification < 5
    if @Classification < 3
        if @Classification = 1
        else . . .
    else if @Classification = 3 . . .
    else . . .
else . . .
```