# Replacing CASE statements with IF statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently, I have been tasked with some major refactoring of a project coded prior to my arrival. Part of this refactoring involves going through some stored procedures and cleaning them up and make some general changes to their behavior. I recently came across the following statement:

```
IF 
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS 
       (
          SELECT *
          FROM users
          WHERE Username = 'admin'
       ) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END <> 0
//Do something here
```

After starring at this piece of code for a while and doing a little research, I eventually came to the conclusion that the logic of the code above can be accomplished by writing:

```
IF EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM users
          WHERE Username = 'admin'
       )
//Do something here
```

**So my question is this:** what would be the advantage to using the case statement? It seems bulkier than the if statement, and less readable too. Is there a compatibility advantage that I'm not seeing? Or am I wrong in saying that these two queries are equivalent, and are there cases where they will behave differently?

As a side note, I'm not terribly concerned in the performance advantages of using CASE statements over if statements. But for those who found themselves on this page looking for just that, [there's a good answer here about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490518/ms-sql-case-vs-if-performance).

Comment: The case statement would be the more optimal option if you were to add other conditions that you would also have to check for to return other results there. If you are only checking the single exists, like in the 2nd example, then that is the better way to go. I agree with you fully.

Comment: I believe the real question here is if `IF` statements shortcut in TSQL.  If they do short cut, then IF ( ) OR ( ) OR ( ) is just as optimal as the CASE.  CASE we know shortcuts at the first check.  I would post this in an answer, however I actually am not sure how TSQL does it.  I think you could test easily enough with a function that inserts a value and returns true, then run it twice with different parameters and see if both get inserted.  Obviously with a single condition to test, it doesn't matter, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainability if one can assume tha more than one condition will be needed over a relatively short timeframe.

Pretty much the only reason I can come up with ;)

Comment: I think second one is easier to maintain

Comment: No, not if you can see 10 or 20 different cases coming up. IF sequences are harder to maintain (easier to get an else condition wrong).

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think of adding additional conditions. Though reasonably, if I keep the weird case statement, anyone I hand the code off to will probably look at with the same confusion that I had! Since I don't see the need for more cases, I've changed it to the IF statement. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of misinformation in some of the comments here.  Fortunately you did change it to an "IF" statement, but for future viewers of this page:

1. See @damien-the-unbeliever's first comment on question here: [MS SQL - CASE vs IF performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490518/ms-sql-case-vs-if-performance#comment25422029_17490518)
2. See forum topic (just the top few posts) here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1206250-392-1.aspx

Basically, the `IF/ELSE` *statements* and `CASE` *expressions* are two fundamentally different parts of the language, and are not used interchangeably.  `IF/ELSE` is for control-flow within a batch or stored-procedure; `CASE` is for "choosing" a data-value within a SELECT or similar operation.